# Order dataframe according to specific deviation percentage (edited)

Tags: r, dataframe, percentage, deviation

Lets say I have the following dataframe:

```
a <- c(0.9,0.8,0.7)
b <- c(1000,200,20)
c <- c(10,20,10)
myframe <- data.frame(a,b,c)

1 0.9 1000 10
2 0.8  200 20
3 0.7   20 10
```

I know want to find the "best" combination subject to the following rules:

- for a higher is better, for b lower is better, for c higher is better
- a trumps b trumps c

I now order the dataframe like this...

```
myframe[with(myframe, order(-a, b, -c))[1],]
```

...and get the following return value:

```
    a    b  c
1 0.9 1000 10
```

I now want to make the way "best" solution is chosen more "intelligent" by checking for the percentage deviation with the result that the second combination is chosen:

```
    a    b  c
2 0.8 200 20
```

1. Change order of dataframe (already achieved, see above)

   order(-a, b, -c)
2. (NEW) Check the b values of all lines where a is not more worse thant 15% of the best a value. Pick the line with the b value that is at least 50% better than the current b value.
3. now line 2 is chosen in case of the example above.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: "This should be done by specific percentages that are defined beforehand. E.g.: if the values for b and c are 50% or one of them is at least 90% better and the value for a is a maximum of 15% worse choose these values." You should really consider rephrasing that, it's barely understandable. Try to make your question as clear as possible so others will be more willing to help you without having to waste time deciphering your goals.

Comment: I edited the Question and I hope my problem is now more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with the data provided, it seems that you only need the `subset`function. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
myframe[with(myframe, order(-a, b, -c))[1],]
best.a = myframe$a[1]
best.b = myframe$b[1]

subset(myframe,a > 0.85*best.a & b < 1.5*best.b)
    a    b  c
1 0.9 1000 10
2 0.8  200 20
```